# Two JmsComponent in One CamelConfiguration with Spring

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-java-config

I am using CameConfiguration to define a CamelContext 
as
public Class Config extends CamelConfiguration
and JmsComponent is defined as below:

@Bean
public JmsComponent activemq(){...}
and in route definition

it is used in route definition as
to(activemq:queue:destinationName)

How do I define two different ActiveMQ JmsComponents as beans with Spring and 
use them in the same or two different routes?

Comment: Further clarification. I am using SINGLE Solace-mq queue in current scenario. My route is defined as  .to(jms:queue:destinationName) with a method name solaceMq1(). Right now, I think Camel figures out that there is only one JmsComponent in the route, so regardless of the method name it uses the JmsComponent provided.

A route like .to(solaceMq1:queue:destinationName) should work, too? Configuring route with .to(solaceMq1: or @bean(name="solaceMq1:" is giving an exception. 

So the question is about using 2 SolaceMQ queues in one route and how to configure and use them as .to("uniqueName".....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 2 methods and give each method a different name, the name of the method is the bean id by default in spring when using `@Bean`, eg

```
@Bean 
public JmsComponent activemq()

@Bean 
public JmsComponent activemq2()
```

And then use `activemq` and `activemq2` in as the component names in the Camel routes.

Comment: Thanks Claus! So I will be using URIs like to(activemq2:queue:destinationName)?

Comment: yes that is correct, also @Bean has an id/name attribute you can set also instead of using the method name

Comment: Would this require any difference in setting up Connection Factories?